# No such file or directory found even though the file is in the same package

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner, hashset, lorem-ipsum

I am trying to scan the `"loremIpsum.txt"` file to a String using the split method of the class String to store each word in a different position of an array, and last use a HashSet to find if there is any word repetition in the text.

But Eclipse doesn't recognize the file even though it is in the same package. I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code?

```
package Lab5;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lorem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] loremIpsum = null;
        try {
            loremIpsum = new Scanner(new File("loremIpsum.txt")).next().split(" ");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(loremIpsum.length);
        HashSet h = new HashSet();

        for(int i=0;i<loremIpsum.length;i++) {
            String word=loremIpsum[i];
            System.out.println(word);
            if(h.contains(word)) {
                System.out.println("we found a duplicate");
            } else {
                h.add(word);
            }   
        }

    }

}
```

Error message and proof "lorem.txt" is in the same package:
[image: error message and proof "lorem.txt" is in the same package]

Comment: Side note: `Scanner#next` uses whitespace as the default delimiter, so calling `split(" ")` will result in a String array of size 1 or possibly 0. You should use `Scanner#nextLine` with `split(" ")`.

Comment: May be an XY problem rather than a duplicate. For a beginning Java exercise, it seems like the problem may lie more with the presumption that the text file is in the same directory as the code, rather than how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

The file will be looked for in the project directory (where `bin` and `src` folders are located). Move the file there.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the File constructor with a relative path, it's relative to the **working directory**.

That usually won't be the same directory as the code calling the constructor. But that's okay, because if your file can be specified when you run the application, you don't want to presume that anyway.

You can specify the working directory in the Eclipse run configuration, on the *Arguments* tab.

You can see how a relative path has been resolved using the File method *getAbsolutePath().*

```
   try {
        File myFile = new File("loremIpsum.txt");
        System.out.println("Absolute path = " + myFile.getAbsolutePath() );

        loremIpsum = new Scanner(myFile).next().split(" ");
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter as a path.

try this

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

path.concat("/loremIpsum.txt");

loremIpsum = new Scanner(new File(path)).next().split(" ");
```

basically youre just finding the current path and appending the file name youre wanting to read from.
Like the others said though, you can move it to your working directory as well.

Cheers!

Comment: The first two statements seem to be a rather roundabout way of accomplishing the same task as `new File("loremIpsum.txt")`.